# Object of type aws-cdk-lib.Resource is not convertible to aws-cdk-lib.aws_eks.Cluster when trying to update the aws-auth ConfigMap

Tags: python, amazon-eks, aws-cdk

While trying to write a simple CDK script to update the aws-auth ConfigMap, I get the error `Object of type aws-cdk-lib.Resource is not convertible to aws-cdk-lib.aws_eks.Cluster`. The error seems to stem from the Cluster reference, but I'm not sure why since `.from_cluster_attributes` returns an ICluster interface.

```py
class EksCdkStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        cluster = eks.Cluster.from_cluster_attributes(self, "Cluster", cluster_name="megaXL")

        role = iam.Role.from_role_arn(self, "Role", "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/delete_me_role")

        eks.AwsAuth(self, "Auth", cluster=cluster).add_role_mapping(role=role, groups="system:masters")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error seems to stem from the Cluster reference, but I'm not sure why since .from_cluster_attributes returns an ICluster interface.

Almost. `AwsAuth` requires a `Cluster`, and you're passing `ICluster`. This means that you can't create an `AwsAuth` resource with an imported Cluster.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that AwsAuth would accept the `ICluster` interface in addition to `Cluster`. Shame that it doesn't work, but that explains it.